# Cache tag helper with vary-by-route attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to use a cache tag helper with vary-by-route attribute but I'm not sure wether my implementation is correct.

My routes are shapped like : http://mywebsite.com/category/job/region/department/city

"category/job/region/department/city" is my path param defined in route's template in Startup.cs :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "DB_Pages",
                    template: "{**path}",
                    defaults: new { controller = PathHelper.GetControllerName<PageController>(), action = nameof(PageController.Page) });
      });
```

I want to cache a menu present on all pages, but the content depends on the url. So I set in my view component output (razor - Default.chtml) :

```
<cache expires-sliding="@TimeSpan.FromHours(24)" vary-by-route="path">
    <!-- Dynamic Html code -->
</cache>
```

But when I access twice to the same url, I don't see any difference. I wonder wether the cache is working.

PS: I have app.UseResponseCaching(); in Startup.cs (I'm not sure this is related)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

Startup:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{path?}");

            });
```

View:

```
<cache expires-sliding="@TimeSpan.FromHours(24)" vary-by-route="path">
    Current Time Inside Cache Tag Helper: @DateTime.Now
</cache>
```

result:
[image]